# qlik sense - KPI to table measure issue using rank

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have the following in a kpi

```
Sum({$<RankNo =   

{"=rank(Only({$<OrderWeekFlag = {1}, [DeliveryDate] =   

{'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'}>

+ 

<OrderWeekFlag = {1}>}RankNo))

<=
$(=sum({$< [DeliveryDate]= {'>=$(=vMinDeliveryWeek)'} , OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}[HasOrder]))

"},OrderWeekFlag = {1} >}
[HasOrder])
```

I need to use this now in a table as a measure with the dimension 'Department', but the numbers are not working because of the rank within the expression. I have tried to use "aggr", "aggr with total" in different places within the expression with no joy.
 
I get different numbers when used in the table for each department, but when I click on an individual department (e.g 'Kitchen') it drills down to the correct number. please help / any ideas?

Comment: code formatting

Comment: This is confusing. Try simplifying it. And/or separating it into two measures. I haven't seen this sort of syntax before. For example it's not clear to me what the '>' on the third line is doing. And the only() should not be used whenever possible because it breaks if you have the wrong dimensions.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the only ().. I have tried really hard to break this expression into two can you please help. its basically customers whom have waited the longest for their delivery's. when I add a dimension into the mix..i get the error please help